# Should I index my sort fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing

I have a field called 'sort_order' and it's bigint, i use it in my mysql queries for sorting.

Is it wise I put an index on it?

Answer (score 6):

Generally, yes.  If you are doing an `ORDER BY` on that field, it should probably be indexed.  Of course you'll want to test it first to make sure it actually helps - if you only ever select a small number of rows it may not make that much of a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Do you honestly expect to have a `sort_order` value that [maxes out at 9,223,372,036,854,775,807](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)?!  Assuming zero based, INT is still pretty large at a max of 2,147,483,647...

Depends on your queries, but I'd look at using it in a covering index before a stand alone one.  [MySQL has a space limit on indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html), you're likely to hit the ceiling if you define an index per column:

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no. You justify indexes with searches. By the time you've reduced the record count to the number you normally display (say, less than several hundred) having an index doesn't buy you anything.

So only add an index if you will use the field for selecting (which would include, say, "LIMIT 500" for instance.)

Comment: Even with limited recordsets, there are shops that want every bit of performance they can get.

Comment: This is almost sure to be a net loss. The "ORDER BY" doesn't benefit if the set is small; and maintaining the index is pure overhead.

Comment: "Generally, no" would not cover the case where a full table read is necessary and an ordered read is beneficial or even necessary?

Comment: The best way to know for sure is to add the index, examine the query plan before and after, and examine the perfomance before and after. (I can't think of a circumstance that requires an ordered read of the records, beyond what the query analyzer determines is optimal.)

Answer (score 2):

As Eric already mentioned above, the answer is Yes.

Although, if you are actually doing a lot of inserts and updates in the table, MySQL builds a separate block of information for indexing that needs to be updated every time there are changes made to the table. Thus the overhead can be there in some cases.

So basically it's a mixed case and the circumstances should always be considered.